# XmlBeansDataBinding in cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf

What is the equivalence for using XmlBeansDataBinding in cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws?

I used XmlBeansDataBinding with Apache cxf and it seems that there isn't in Spring Boot cxf.

Answer (score 1):

using spring starter cxf and cxf databinding lib with annotation in the @webservices interface :@Databinding(XmlBeansDataBinding.class) fix the problem